# Can I define molecular units on NBO3.1 or NBO6.0?

Tags: density-functional-theory, computational-chemistry, quantum-chemistry, electronic-structure, gaussian

I'm studying donor-acceptor charge transfer (CT) process between tetrakis(m2-acetato)-di-Wolframium (acceptor) with an acetonitrile (donor) at the B3LYP-D3BJ/def2-TZVPD level of theory.

The W···N distance is 2.61 Å and the angle W-W···N was fixed at 180º. I have partially optimized the adduct to avoid the rotation of the donor. There is a quadruple bond between the Wolframium atoms.

The cartesian coordinates of the adduct are:

```
0 1
H    0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000
H    0.0000000   0.0000000   1.7650960
H    1.5429470   0.0000000   0.9065370
C    0.5213070  -0.3730010   0.8792100
C    0.5115790  -1.8689030   0.8948480
O    1.4655670  -2.4948790   1.4672170
O   -0.4647780  -2.4927580   0.3591350
H    2.7298470  -3.6680600  -2.9986060
H    1.9706890  -5.2000210  -3.4371030
H    3.5225890  -5.1796590  -2.5462560
C    2.5558000  -4.6963860  -2.6703410
C    1.8106380  -4.6804330  -1.3731820
O    2.4639640  -4.6623740  -0.2766710
O    0.5343070  -4.6600980  -1.3859230
H   -1.0577910  -4.8324740   5.4363250
H   -2.6092990  -4.8775190   4.5457670
H   -1.8106250  -3.3379350   4.8714100
C   -1.6398010  -4.3907740   4.6303730
C   -0.8949760  -4.4850660   3.3364290
O    0.3812400  -4.5107210   3.3493710
O   -1.5483540  -4.5084530   2.2399960
H    0.9184040  -9.1694920   0.2023810
H   -0.6281090  -9.1684040   1.0549360
H    0.9111970  -9.1680240   1.9674410
C    0.3935240  -8.7957550   1.0857700
C    0.4037100  -7.2998970   1.0690450
O    1.3802450  -6.6758970   1.6044770
O   -0.5501320  -6.6737680   0.4963230
W   -0.4821270  -4.5837890   0.4415910
W    1.4118140  -4.5859810   1.5299720
N    3.6765230  -4.5886000   2.8313670
C    4.6704280  -4.5897500   3.4025290
C    5.9313900  -4.5913140   4.1272610
H    5.8057380  -5.0702300   5.0985750
H    6.6884250  -5.1359940   3.5626120
H    6.2768810  -3.5689200   4.2820320
```

Tetrakis(m2-acetato)-di-Wolframiun: atoms 1-30.

Acetonitrile: atoms 31-36.

When I perform an NBO calculation (v3.1), the program considers the whole assembly as the same molecular unit. There are two artificial NBO, BD W30-N31 and BD* W30-N31, with an occupancy of 1.955 and 0.145 electrons, respectively.

Performing the same calculation with NBO v6.0, the program divides the adduct in three molecular units.

Unit 1: acetate ion (atoms 1-7). Charge -0.574

Unit 2: tris(m2-acetato)-di-Wolframiun ion (atoms 8-30) Charge +0.511

Unit 3: Acetonitrile (atoms 31-36) Charge: 0.062

I'm only interested on CT process involved on the stability of the noncovalent bond between the N-donor and the W-acceptor. For NBO6.0 calculation the acetonitrile is an independent moiety. Nevertheless, I'm not sure if the results I obtained are reliable due to the di-Wolframiun adduct is divided in two units (1 and 2).

So,

Can I define molecular units on NBO3.1 or NBO6.0? I want to define the whole tetrakis(m2-acetato)-di-Wolframiun compound as unit 1 and the acetonitrile as unit 2.

Thank you in advance.